# Trouble adding a backend to statsd

Tags: node.js

```
npm install -g statds
npm install -g statsd-ganglia-backend
```

This does not deliver the new backend to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/statsd/backends.

What do I need to copy for myself?

Answer (score 0):

The doc for neglects to mention that you install it *inside* of statsd. You cd to the statsd directory and to a local, not a global, install.